# Call to a member function on a non-object error symfony2

Tags: forms, events, object, symfony

This is an odd one. I have this method, that is the callback for the `FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA` event in an EventSubscriber of a form in Symfony2:

```
public function preSetData(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        $resource_provider = $data->getResourceProvider();
        $type = $resource_provider->getType(); //PROBLEM HERE

        \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump(is_object($resource_provider));
}
```

It has more code but the error is firing in the line with the comment `PROBLEM HERE`.

The issue is that the dump there prints `bool(true)`, so it is an object, and have the data inside, but trying to call `getType()`, that exist, fails with this error:

```
Error: Call to a member function getType() on a non-object
```

To add more confusion, if I dump `$resource_provider->getType()` I get the expected content dumped, but the error remains.

Does someone knows or has a clue on what can be happening here?

EDIT

Can't believe it! I found the answer, but doesn't makes sense at all! I had to wrap the problematic code with a conditional like this:

```
if(is_a($resource_provider, 'My\Bundle\Path\Entity\ResourceProvider')){}
```

and it worked! If someone can tell me what is the sense of that, I will happily select his/her answer as correct.

Comment: Does it work if you subscribe to POST_SUBMIT (POST_BIND in symfony < 2.3)?

Comment: Well, the thing is that I'm trying to work with the form prior to show it, cannot use POST_SUBMIT.

Comment: The problem is that you're trying to get the type with getType() while $resource_provider is null and not an object so there is an error. By adding your condition, you're avoiding the problem because you don't call getType() if $resource_provider is null, but only if it's the expected object !

Comment: Sorry @Sybio, but you're wrong. As I said in my question, the dump showed that the object was there and had data. It was not null. Now the conditional is not acting as a conditional(is always true) in my tests, since every time the object is populated. That's the odd thing. If I remove the conditional, no matter what, I get the error.

Comment: Yes but this is perhaps because the event is call one time and the $resource_provider is well defined, and after submission of the form or something else, $resource_provider is null and the event called a second time. Are you sure that your event is not called 2 times in your action ? Before and after form submission for example ? You should log this (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/logging/monolog.html) and print "ok" if it's an object and "wrong" is null. Or simpler if only it's not an object, do a print_r of $resource_provider; and an exit; to see its value.

Comment: Well @Sybio, this time makes more sense and yes, you're right, the method is being called twice, though I don't really know were the double calling is happening, because it is set up to be called once.

Comment: @Sybio, please, format it as an answer so I can select it as correct. It really leads me towards solving my doubt, so you deserve it.

Comment: It's done, hope it helped to debug ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that $resource_provider is probably null as error says $resource_provider is not an object.

When printing the value of $resource_provider and skipping the script, it shows the right object of class 'My\Bundle\Path\Entity\ResourceProvider' :

```
echo get_class($resource_provider); exit; // Display My\Bundle\Path\Entity\ResourceProvider and skip the script
```

When adding a condition to test is the object is of the expected class, the script doesn't crash anymore :

```
if(is_a($resource_provider, 'My\Bundle\Path\Entity\ResourceProvider')){}
```

In addition, when skipping script when it's not an object, $resource_provider is null and the script skipped :

```
if(is_a($resource_provider, 'My\Bundle\Path\Entity\ResourceProvider')){

} else {
   var_dump($resource_provider); exit;
}
```

$resource_provider is an object and null in the same "execution" of the script.

So we can deduce that the EventSubcriber is loaded more than one time, perhaps before the form binding and after form binding for example and the first time with the expected object, and a second (or more) time with no value, as null, perhaps because the $resource_provider is not filled when submitting form or something else.